# How to use RewriteCond to get rid of duplicate page

Tags: .htaccess

**Hello guys! I need some help with htaccess, because I'm really stuck with it. I have some pages, like:**

> site.ru/books
>
> site.ru/pens

**And those links can be called by other urls:**

> site.ru/index.php?show=books
>
> site.ru/index.php?show=pens

I hope you understand those links above are equal. Just, urls are user friendly.

I want to use RewriteCond to make a redirect from "site.ru/index.php?show=books" to "site.ru/books", because Google or other Search Engines don't like duplicate pages.

But the problem is I don't know how to write this… Help me please, and sorry for my bad English ;-)

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?show=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?show=$1 [L,QSA]
```